# Login system (No GUI) giving wrong output

Tags: python, database, function

I am trying to make a non-graphical login system.

I am expecting the `Register()` to take a username and password from the user, then from that open the file which stores the current data and see if the username exists already. From this it either creates the accounts and stores the info and if its taken it makes them re put in a new username. If I put in a name which already exists it will still create the account and store the info. What can I do?

Probably an easy fix with alot of bad code but I have been learning for under 2 week!
Here is the code:

````py
def start():
    global option
    option =  input('Welcome to Skies site!\nLogin or register?: ')
    if (option != 'login' and option != 'register'):
        print('Invalid input, try again.')
        start()
    elif option == 'login':
        Login()
    elif option == 'register':
        Register()

def Login(username, password):
    success = False # Set false so login isnt set to true at start
    file = open('user_details.txt','r') #R is read mode it will read the file
    for i in file:
        a,b = i.split(',') #Split on bases of comma to get the name and password
        b = b.strip() #Removes new line character (new empty line)
        if (a==username and b==password):
            success = True
            break
    file.close()
    if success == True:
        print('Login Successful!')
    else:
        print('Wrong username or password. Try again.')

def Register():
    global username
    username = input('Enter username: ')
    password = input('Enter password: ')
    with open('user_details.txt','a+') as file:
        if username in file.readlines():
            print('Username taken. Try another')
            Register()
        else:
            print('Username available!')
            file.write('\n'+username+' , '+password)
            print('Credentials Saved!')
            print('--> Log in now <--')
            Login(username, password)

def user_info(username, password, verify):
    print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>')
    print('Account is: ACTIVE')
    print('Username: '+username)

start()```

Thanks for in advance!
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
def Register():
  global username
  username = input('Enter username: ')
  password = input('Enter password: ')
  with open('user_details.txt','r+') as file:
    if str(username) in str(file.readlines()):
      print('Username taken. Try another')
      Register()
    else:
        print('Username available!')
        file.write(username+' , '+password+'\n')
        print('Credentials Saved!')
        print('--> Log in now <--')
        Login(username, password)
```

Comment: That works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You must use SQL database not text file for save informations!!

Comment: I understand that, it was only using for my own purpose to try and use def to make a login system. I haven't learned anything to do with SQL currently but once I have better understanding in Python I will definitely be learning and understanding SQL.

Answer (score 0):

````
  global username
  username = input('Enter username: ')
  password = input('Enter password: ')
  with open('user_details.txt','r+') as file:
    if str(username) in str(file.readlines()):
      print('Username taken. Try another')
      Register()
    else:
        print('Username available!')
        file.write(username+' , '+password+'\n')
        print('Credentials Saved!')
        print('--> Log in now <--')
        Login(username, password)```
````

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).